# Using subquery with IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I am stuck at one particular problem here, I am fetching ID's from one column that are like this `',90132988,90133148,72964884,'` Let's say this value is stored in a column ColumnA of Table1.

I want to use this in another query that's using IN clause something like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER_GROUP 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('(',REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(COLUMNA, ',', ' '))), ' ', ',')),')') FROM Table1)
```

When I run this query I get invalid number error. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is the data type of "ID" and "COLUMNA"?

Comment: @Acroyear The datatype of ID is BIGINT and the columnA is multilist column so it's VARCHAR daatype

Comment: There is your problem. You have to convert one side or the other so you are comparing like data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a number error because `id` is a number.  So, Oracle wisely assumes that the subquery returns numbers.

I think the logic you want is:

```
SELECT ug.*
FROM USER_GROUP ug
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Table1 t1
              WHERE t1.COLUMNA LIKE '%,' || ug.ID || ',%'
             );
```

I strongly discourage you from storing number lists as strings.  Just store one row per number.  That is really much simpler and the resulting code will be more efficient.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask again but as I have marked it complete would you be able to also tell me how to use 2 exists in same query ? I want to use another column from Table1 with User Group table having same type of vaules

Comment: @MuhammadAsim . . . You would just add `and exists . . . ` to the end of the query.

Comment: Well I was hoping that's would work but I don't understand query kept executing and doesn't stop. Well I'll have a look. Do I need to use User Group table again with another alias ? I tried both ways though

Comment: Does a NULL column affect this query if ColumnA is null

Comment: @MuhammadAsim . . . `NULL` will not match anything.  That is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting "ID" using `TO_CHAR`, but you will lose the use of any index on ID if you have one.

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER_GROUP 
WHERE TO_CHAR(ID) IN (SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('(',REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(COLUMNA, ',', ' '))), ' ', ',')),')') FROM Table1)
```